# The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version when using Python

Tags: python, mysql, macos, mysql-python

I am getting the following error message when I run this program on a mac. It works fine on the original Linux computer:

```
File "setupPpiDb.py", line 406, in modules

createDataBase(pdbsToAnalyzeWithChains)

File "setupPpiDb.py", line 202, in createDataBase

''' %(os.path.join(RESULTS_DIR, 'PerAtomDistance.csv')))

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 250, in execute

  self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler

   raise errorvalue

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 247, in execute

    res = self._query(query)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 412, in _query

   rowcount = self._do_query(q)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 375, in _do_query

    db.query(q)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 276, in query

   _mysql.connection.query(self, query)

_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1148, 'The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version')
```

I am running Python3 on a mac and downloaded the latest community download version MySQL Database. The complete command is the following:

```
cursor.execute('''
load data local infile '%s' into table interfaceDist fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' ignore 1 lines (PDB,Chains,Chain,ResId,Symbol,Atom,MinDist);
''' %(os.path.join(RESULTS_DIR, 'PerAtomDistance.csv')))
```

I have read that people have issues the local infile command. However, it has a problem with the second line of the command and I connect to the database in the following way with local_infile=1:

MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user=USER, passwd=PASSWD, db=DB_NAME, local_infile=1)

Any ideas on how to fix the bug?

Comment: What MySQL version specifically?

Comment: mysql  Ver 8.0.11 for osx10.13 on x86_64 (Homebrew)

Comment: It may be to do with the `LOCAL` part of the query, so I'd try and confirm with and without that through another MySQL connection (e.g. `mysql` shell or MySQL Workbench). MySQL 8+ has broken some old MySQL drivers, so you could also try the latest 5.7 version.